# Transfer a file from a computer to an Azure VM

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a vb.net application connected with an sql server. This applications handles files.

Recently, this application connected with an sql server, which is in a VM of Azure.

My question is, how i can hanndle the files?

I want my application to upload(over internet) the files somewhere and then server side to haddle where these files will be saved. And the opposite.

Can you tell me what options i have? I don't want OneDrive.

Comment: you could just upload them using ftp or sth. like that

Comment: what kind of files? ( .vhd files, text, documents, images ...etc? ).

Comment: Usually documents like pdf, word etc & images

Comment: @S3minaki then if you don't mind these files being arranged in directories in structured manner, Azure Blob Storage might be your best choice. Otherwise use SMB protocol with Azure Files ( see detailed answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the kinds of files you store and the way your application handles them, you have multiple options with Azure. These are Azure Blob Storage ( with blob types: Block, Append, and Page), Azure Files, or Azure Data Lake Store.

[Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/):
The following blob types are great of your data is unstructured.

- Block Blobs: for use of binary data or text. You store in blocks that can be manged.
- Page Blobs: to store random access files, good for storing VHDs that are backing up VMs.
- Append Blobs: similar to block blobs but are append-only and optimized for append-only workloads. Good for storing log files storage.

If you handle files using native file systems APIs and want to "lift and shift" your application as is, [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api) might be your best option which uses the SMB protocol.

Another option you might want to try, which is in preview (not generally available yet ) is [Azure Data Lake Store Gen 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2) which allows you to interact with Azure Blob storage through a file system interface.

From the way you describe your application, I doubt you want to use Azure Disks service. Here is a comparison table to help you decide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json